# function to check a text field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

im using access 2007 and i need a function that will check a text field and if it found a certain word it will return a certain value according to lookup table

for example i have a text field as following  :

```
    ID                   Text
|    1     |  engineers for mechanical work  
|    2     |  engineers for civil work       
|    3     |  engineers for electrical work
```

and i have lookup table as following :

```
     Checkwords             showords
 |   mechanical      |   mechanical engineer
 |   civil           |   civil engineer
 |   chemical        |   chemical engineer
 |   electrical      |   electrical engineer
 |   maintenance     |   maintenance engineer
 |   electronics     |   electronics engineer
```

i need the function to check the text records and if it found text like "*mechanical*" it will show "mechanical engineer" and if it found text like "*civil*" it will show "civil engineer" and so on

i have about 200 words to check so i need a function that uses a lookup table with "like" parameter ... is that possible ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK then, a more generic version, though be warned - the more you lean on VBA rather than SQL, the slower things get with large and even not-so-large amounts of data:

(1) Add a class module, name it LookupData, and add the following fields to it:

```
Public Key As String
Public Value As String
```

(2) In a standard module, define the following function:

```
Function LookupShowWords(ByVal Text)
  If IsNull(Text) Then
    LookupShowWords = Null
    Exit Function
  End If
  Dim Data As LookupData
  Static LookupTable As VBA.Collection
  If LookupTable Is Nothing Then
    Set LookupTable = New VBA.Collection
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("LookupTable", dbOpenForwardOnly)
    While Not RS.EOF
      Set Data = New LookupData
      Data.Key = "*" + RS(0) + "*"
      Data.Value = RS(1)
      LookupTable.Add Data
      RS.MoveNext
    Wend
  End If
  Dim S As String
  For Each Data In LookupTable
    If Text Like Data.Key Then
      If Len(S) = 0 Then
        S = Data.Value
      Else
        S = S + ";" + Data.Value
      End If
    End If
  Next
  If Len(S) = 0 Then LookupShowWords = Null Else LookupShowWords = S
End Function
```

(3) The query to list the results can now be rewritten to look simply like this:

```
SELECT ID, LookupShowWords(Text) AS ShowWords FROM MainTable ORDER BY ID;
```

Note that the assumption in (2) is that the lookup table is essentially static, in which case its contents can be safely cached between calls.

Answer (score 0):

(1) A custom VBA function to extract the key word:

```
Function ExtractKeyword(ByVal Text)
  Text = Mid(Text, InStr(Text, " for ") + 5)
  If Right(Text, 5) = " work" Then
    ExtractKeyword = Left(Text, Len(Text) - 5)
  Else
    ExtractKeyword = Text
  End If
End Function
```

(2) A query to use it:

```
SELECT MainTable.ID, LookupTable.ShowWords
FROM MainTable LEFT JOIN
     LookupTable ON ExtractKeyword(MainTable.Text) = LookupTable.CheckWords
ORDER BY MainTable.ID
```

Comment: thank you , good work but your function works only if the text has the same words as in the example , i have fields with different words is there any other way to use  %checkwords% inside the function so no matter what words exist in the text field ?

Comment: @user1921704 What was the point of the very standardised example data then...? Less rhetorically, what should happen if there is more than one match? I ask because multiple matches will be possible if you really want an entirely generic solution.

Comment: if there is more than one match is it possible to return all of them in one field for example if the function found the words "civil" and "mechanical" it will return "civil engineer;mechanical engineer" ??

Comment: @user1921704 - Argh, the requirements are getting even worse! ;-) I'll amend my second suggestion accordingly.